# Can't get pygame1.9.4 modules to work

Tags: pygame

Has anyone been able to get this to work with Python 3.4 64-bit?  I was able to install via pip.  I can type "import pygame"

```
>>> import pygame
>>>
```

in idle, I can't seem to access any of its methods/ modules i.e. pygame.image

```
>>> import pygame.image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame.image
ImportError: No module named 'pygame.image'
```

I'm running Win 7 64bit on intel i5 - (do I need any AMD processor to run this ??)

Comment: What does ls / dir show in the working directory? Do you by any chance have a pygame.py file in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Pygame mayn't be installed properly. Try reinstalling.